# Does anyone know the name of the Russian person here?

Tags: перевод

[image]

I am not sure who he is does anyone know? Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about the Russian language.

Comment: This is the less constructive vote of all the counterproductive suggestions made by the YS here so far, because it suggests the most narrow-minded view on the Russian and Post-Soviet culture, ignoring visual arts and cultural code.

Comment: Hahaha! @Manjusri is in his domain, commenting on cartoon characters is the field where his idiosyncracy can go unleashed. We're talking about the Russian language here, how can cartoon characters be related to the language?

Comment: Flag your comment again. Just not sure whether it is more 'rude and offensive' or 'counter-productive'. I think it's more counter-productive, because you don't understand that a language is a living totality of cultural codes, and that cartoons and other visual arts are part of it. So flag your comment as not constractive.

Comment: Cultural codes have nothing to do with language, or should the Russian traditions of drinking vodka be also discussed here on the Russian Language SE? :D

Comment: Do you really don't get the relation between cultural codes and languages,  or are you just kidding around?

Comment: @Manjusri I have to ask you to be more respectful and constructive to the others - even when they disagree with you.

Comment: @shabunc Not when they are insulting me or show other traits of their stupidity. I treat different people differently, so your claim has no grounds and my ethics are my business and none of yours.

Answer (score 4):

The robbers' characters from the cartoon "По следам бременских музыкантов" ([On the Trail of the Bremen Town Musicians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On_the_Trail_of_the_Bremen_Town_Musicians)) are, in their turn, the replicas of the physical appearance of the three criminals from the 60's comedy "Кавказская пленница" ([Kidnapping Caucasian Style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kidnapping,_Caucasian_Styl)).

[The prototype movie characters](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81,_%D0%91%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%81_%D0%B8_%D0%91%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8B%D0%B9) (in Russian) represented at the cartoon cadre are known as (from seer's left to right) Trus (The Coward), Byvalyi (The Pro) and Balbes (The Fool) respectively. Since 60s, they are present in many Russian humorous folk stories.

The Fool's character is played by [Yury Nikoolin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yuri_Nikulin).

Trivia: in the cartoon, when the robbers sing 'We Don't Want To Live It Another Way', The Coward starts stuttering on syllables 'yu - ra', which is a conversational form of the name Yury.

Comment: Yoory Neekooleen - that's how that name is spelled correctly.

Comment: I understand your sarcasm, but being sarcastic and counter-productive is  just being rude and arrogant. So flag your comment.

Comment: Using such idiosyncratic spelling of a famous name is not in the traditions of SE. If you goole it, you'll see that there's _not a single_ instance of such a spelling on the internet. https://www.google.com/search?client=opera&q="Yury+Nikoolin"&sourceid=opera&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8

Comment: YS, please. No Internet data doesn't actually prove anything except its own availability.I can goole, google or even ghoule it, but that wouldn't help you a lot. Corpus method doesn't go well with cognitive sciences. The purpose of this site is to help people to understand the Russian language without making it more difficult than it already is.So it can be as well Yoory Neekoolin or Yuriy Nekoolin or even Jurij Nikulin, whatever.

Comment: M, you know it yourself how weird your spelling is. I have no intent to prove you're wrong, everyone can see that without any proof. I know you'd never acknowlege that, but mind, persisting in one's own folliies means acknowleging them, the more you persist, the more vivid your follies are.

Comment: It's not spelling. It's the transliteration.

Comment: Ah, transliteration. Usually you do it like this: _Yuri Nikulin (YOO-rih nee-KOO-lin)_ Thus the reader will be able to see both the original spelling and the way it's pronounced. My intent is not insulting you, it's just making your otherwise very good comments more user-friendly, please, don't indulge into idiosyncracy, write it all the way others will understand, that's all.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58036/discussion-on-answer-by-manjusri-does-anyone-know-the-name-of-the-russian-person).